# Bot Framework save CONVERSATION_REFERENCES to the list or array

Tags: python, botframework

I have problem with bot `CONVERSATION_REFERENCES`, it only saves one `conversation_reference` (latest). I want save them all.

For example
Then I call or add bot in the chat in Microsoft teams, code save `conversation_reference`. If I add bot in another chat or call bot it looks like overwrite  `conversation_reference`, and I only have latest `conversation_reference`, but for example if I want to send proactive message to all chats where was bot called or add, it only send in latest chat.

So I need change function to save `conversation_reference` to array or list, but i cant found solution how to do it correctly.  `Bot.py`

```
  def __init__(
    self, 
    conversation_references: Dict[list, ConversationReference],
    timestamp: str = None,
    channel_id: str = None,
    prompted_for_user_name: bool = False
):
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.channel_id = channel_id
    self.prompted_for_user_name = prompted_for_user_name
    self.conversation_references = conversation_references

   def _add_conversation_reference(self, activity: Activity):
        """
        This populates the shared Dictionary that holds conversation references. In this sample,
        this dictionary is used to send a message to members when /api/notify is hit.
        :param activity:
        :return:
        """
        conversation_reference = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(activity)
        print(f"Adding new conversation to the list: {conversation_reference}")
        self.conversation_references[
            conversation_reference.user.id
        ] = conversation_reference
```

In `app.py` I change it too, from `str` to `list`

```
CONVERSATION_REFERENCES: Dict[list, ConversationReference] = dict()
```

In `def _add_conversation_reference(self, activity: Activity):` function I try change this line.

```
conversation_reference = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(activity)
```

After I try transform it like this

```
conversation_reference =[]
conversation_reference.append(TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(activity))
```

I getting error like this

```
        return await callback(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\botbuilder\core\activity_handler.py", line 71, in on_turn
    await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
  File "C:\bots\proactive_bot.py", line 52, in on_message_activity
    self._add_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)
  File "C:\bots\proactive_bot.py", line 67, in _add_conversation_reference
    conversation_reference.user.id
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Why I need this? Because I want make bot who can send proactive messages to all chats where he was. But if it only saves latest `conversation_reference`, I can only send proactive message to one chat.

For proactive message send in `app.py` code

```
   async def _send_proactive_message():
        for conversation_reference in CONVERSATION_REFERENCES.values():
            print(f"converstion reference: {conversation_reference}")
            await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
                conversation_reference,
                lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity(split),
                APP_ID,
            )
        print(CONVERSATION_REFERENCES.values())
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem? Thank you.

Comment: You say you've made changes. What have you made changes to? Are you following a specific sample? Can you link to it? Have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?tabs=python

Comment: @Kyle Delaney I don't do important changes for keeping conversation referfences. I give example, how i try solve problem with what saves only one conversation reference (latest). of course I read this article, from it I pick logic and code for my bot.

Comment: That's good that you've read the doc, but it doesn't look like you're following it. Can you please answer my other questions?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: no, I store conversation references objects in azure blob, and then call it in proactive message function

Comment: No you're not still working on this? Does that mean you've solved your issue? Would you like to post your solution as an answer so that you can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking code like this.

1. **Define in app.py**
   CONVER_REF : Dict[str,ConversationReference] = dict()
2. **Ctor assgin**

self.conv_ref = conver_ref -> pass as ctor argu

**3. async def on_members_added_activity store the get_conversation_reference**

con_obj = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)
self.conv_ref[con_obj.user.id] = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)

**4.Proactive function execute**

```
        for conversation_reference in self.conv_ref.values(): 
        await self.adapter.continue_conversation(
        conversation_reference,
        lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity("proactive hello"),APPID,)
```

In my sample I have tested the use case , If new user connect to the bot I send message to others users ( Just call proactive function for testing purpose)
here video sample : [output video](https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample/blob/master/Python_tutorial/stackoverflow_answers/proactive.mp4)

Comment: thank for help, but your code not working, first how you call ```self``` in ```app,py```, second without ```self``` It only send in one chat, not multiple like you show in video.

Comment: define 
app.pyCONVERSATION_REFERENCES: Dict[str, ConversationReference] = dict()

in same file app.py define below function

async def _send_proactive_message():
    for conversation_reference in CONVERSATION_REFERENCES.values():
        await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
            conversation_reference,
            lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity("proactive hello"),
            APP_ID,
        )

Comment: But its the same, as i got from 
at the beginning, it only saves one con reference, and then i will try save more, its just overwrite it .

Comment: in which function gets  overwrite it .

Comment: I think in here ```self.conv_ref[con_obj.user.id] = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)``` after i try print it, i only get one ```dict``` and if i add bot in another team, i only get one value like this ```dict_values([<botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ConversationReference object at 0x0000027315EDC2B0>])```